# Neo4j Admin Import Database not Available in Console

Tags: neo4j

I have a successful import using the bin/neo4j-admin tool, can see the new database folder in my /databases, have restarted the server, but cannot get the database to appear in the console as an option to switch to. Do you have any suggestions for getting a newly imported database to be available in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are referring to the Neo4j Desktop environment.

The Desktop currently seems to be designed to support local DBs created by the Desktop itself.

As a workaround, you can:

1. Create a new "Graph" in the Desktop, using the "Connect to Remote Graph" option.
2. Accept the default "bolt://localhost:7687" as the `Connect URL` (assuming the default is acceptable).
3. Manually start your local neo4j installation from the command line, and
4. Click `Connect` on your "Graph" to connect.

Be aware that the Desktop has fewer bells and whistles for "remote
   graphs".

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The steps I found to successfully import a set of CSV using the admin -import tool is to:

1. Stop the server
2. Run the admin -import tool and use --database=aDatabaseName
3. Start the server
4. In the console switch to the System database using the pulldown control
5. Run the following command at the system prompt: `create database aDatabaseName` 
   (should be the same name set in #2 above)
6. Switch to the database just created using the console pulldown control

I was able to see the database nodes and relationships I created following the above steps

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I was trying to access my database generated through neo4j-admin on my Neo4j Desktop app browser console.

1. On Neo4j Desktop App open the browser of the database server you want to include  the new database
2. Switch to the system database https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases/

```
:use system
```

3. as system, create the database you want to import

```
:create database dbname
```

4. Stop the server
5. Use the neo4-admin tool to import the database https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-training/v4/19-using-neo4j-admin-tool-import/ (make sure to use the same name **--database dbname**). Run these command on the terminal opened from the Desktop app under the databases>_Open Terminal. On windows the neo4j-admin.bat is located in the bin directory
6. start the server and open the neo4j browser and switch to the system database https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases/

```
:use system
```

7. To list all the database available to use as system

```
:dbs
```

8. switch to your imported database

```
:use dbmame
```

9. Your browser console is ready now for your queries.